# Tensor of Lists: how to convert to tensor of one list?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torch

I have a tensor like this

```
tensor([[4.],[1.]], device='cuda:0')
```

I wanna change to the following:

```
tensor([4.,1.], device='cuda:0')
```

How to do that?

I am not sure if this is the reason for the error:

```
loss = nn.MSELoss(y_tilde,y)

RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 2):

using

```
torch.flatten()
```

example:

```
t = torch.tensor([[[1, 2],
                   [3, 4]],
                  [[5, 6],
                 [7, 8]]])
out: tensor([[[1, 2],
         [3, 4]],

        [[5, 6],
         [7, 8]]])
torch.flatten(t)
out: tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```